# Guest User permission problem on update operation

Tags: permissions, guest-user, unsubscribe

I am using the AppExchange [Unsubscribe Link package](https://appexchange.salesforce.com/appxListingDetail?listingId=a0N3A00000FMkfNUAT&_ga=2.38107363.133670019.1658087659-2010957430.1657892557) (from Salesforce Labs) (version installed 3.10.0) and I get the following error when I try to unsubscribe a Lead or Contact:

> FIELD_CUSTOM_VALIDATION_EXCEPTION: Insufficient permissions: secure query included inaccessible field

I think that this is related to the security policies incorporated on Summer '20 for guest users for not allow **update and delete records**, only **create and read**.

As the unsubscribe link needs a guest user (unauthenticated user) for the requeriment makes sense and it must **update** the field **HasOptedOutOfEmail** from Contact or Lead, I don't how to by pass the error.

I tried the following:

1. I check that the error ocurrs when the packages attempt an update on Contact or Lead. That happen on update flow component.
2. I check the permissions and adding the guest user to "Unsubscribe Link" permission set.
3. I check that all the Flows of the packages runs as System mode without colaboration (see all data).
4. I create manual sharing rules for guest user to the Contact and Lead objects in order that that user can see all data.
5. I removed the update flow component that causes the error and replaced it by a trigger that is mounted on the Unsubscribe Link custom object.This record is created before that the Contact or Lead update. Same error.
6. I moved the apex logic from the trigger to a class with *without sharing* keyword on the definition of the class and creating a static method with the update logic. Same error.
7. I make the static method as @future. Same error.
8. I change the static method in an instance method. Same error.
9. I make an @InvocableMethod that is invoked from the same flow. Same error.

What can I do for bypass this error and Salesforce allow me to update the Lead or Contact record with the guest user?

Thanks!

Comment: did you follow the [setup & troubleshooting instructions](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1saNpdkeTU17BbPGw5jTZpjUDt_bJ8HbexAULHxrj-xI/edit)? There is also a contact point to email the author for additional help

Comment: Yeah! I follow all these instructions. I'm in contact with the author too, thanks!